# How do i add g++ to my path?

Tags: linux, bash, c++

I have g++ installed on my Linux computer. It is not in my path. I am a beginner at all of this, and do not know how to set it to my path. I have tried looking it up, but have not found any answers online. Could you please tell me how to set g++ to my path?

Comment: If you used a standard install of g++, it is very unlikely that `g++` is not in your `PATH`. Normally, `g++` would be `/usr/bin/g++` and `/usr/bin` is almost certainly in your `PATH`. So it is likely that you have another problem. To be sure, could you update the question with the output of `ls -ld /usr/bin/g++` and `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

The `PATH` environment variable is used to search for executable files.

An example value might be:

```
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/share/bin
```

This is a colon (`:`) separated list of directories, and when a name is given that isn't a relative (`./gcc`) or absolute (`/home/attie/bin/gcc`), then the shell will search each of these in turn.

For example, if you gave `gcc`, then the shell would search the following paths, stopping at the first that matches an existing file:

1. `/bin/gcc`
2. `/usr/bin/gcc`
3. `/usr/share/bin/gcc`

You can list all elements of this search that match an executable by running `which -a gcc`

---

If you've installed the toolchain in `/home/attie/toolchain`, perhaps with the executables in `/home/attie/toolchain/bin`, then you can *append* this to your path like so:

```
PATH="${PATH}:/home/attie/toolchain/bin"
```

The `${PATH}` expands out to the current (previous) value of the environment variable, you add a colon / separator (`:`), and then add your new directory.

Now, `/home/attie/toolchain/bin/gcc` will be appended (as #4) in the search above.

---

If the system `gcc` is located first and you'd like to "*override*" it, then you'll want to prepend the directory instead:

```
PATH="/home/attie/toolchain/bin:${PATH}"
```

After which, `/home/attie/toolchain/bin/gcc` will be "*prepended*" (before #1) in the search above.

---

To share this new `PATH` with sub processes, you'll want to run `export PATH` as well.

---

To make this permanent, you can add the relevant line with the `export` keyword to your `~/.bashrc` file (or equivalent). As an example, I maintain a set of "*useful scripts*" in `/home/attie/.bin`, so I have the following line in my `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="~/.bin:${PATH}"
```